# Computing power spectrum from CSV file

Tags: c++, csv, dft

I need to compute the power spectrum of a non-linear oscillator in a CSV file (The CSV file has 2 columns to graph the oscillator's displacement with time). I have managed to get an output with the code below, but it isn't correct. I have troubleshooted and am quite sure the problem lies in the two for-loops applying the discrete fourier transform. Any help/tips are appreciated.

I have a CSV file that I assign one of the columns to an array,

```
while (fileInput.good()){
      getline( fileInput, value, ',' );
      istringstream iss(value); // string stream
      getline(iss, time, ','); // read first part up to comma, ignore the comma
      iss >> disp; // read the second part

      inData[columnSize] = atof(disp.c_str());
      columnSize++;
        }
```

The array then is *supposed* to have a discrete fourier transform applied to it using

```
for (k = 0; k < n; k++) {  // For each output element 
        long double sumreal = 0;
        long double sumimag = 0;
        int t;
        for (t = 0; t < n; t++) {  // For each input element 

            double angle = ( 2.0 * 3.141593 * t * k )/ n;
            sumreal += inData[t]  * cos(angle);
            sumimag += inData[t]  * sin(angle);
        }


        DFToutput << k << ',' << (pow(sumreal,2) + pow(sumimag, 2)) << endl;

    }
```

Since my input array is purely real, I omitted the imaginary input found in [this link](http://www.nayuki.io/page/how-to-implement-the-discrete-fourier-transform) on DFTs.

Comment: The angle computation looks suspect, with roughly n*2*pi as max value.

Comment: `sumimag += -inData...`

Comment: How you know your output is incorrect? What are your test cases?

Comment: It was a mixture between @MarkSetchell and the first commenter. I changed the first for loop to a max value of n/2 (as the power spectrum was mirrored around the centre of the plot in the above code). I also needed to change the sign on the imaginary sum. Thanks for your help!